# Suppose that I picked a subset $X\subset\mathbb{R}$ of the real numbers. How to compute the probability of $X$ to have null Lebesgue measure?

Tags: probability-theory, lebesgue-measure

If I pick a set $X\subset\mathbb{R}$ in real line, which is the probability to have $m(X) = 0$. The probability is null?

(apologize the bad English)

Comment: For this to make sense, you need to give the power set of $\mathbb{R}$ (or maybe some subset thereof, such as the Lebesgue measurable sets) a probability measure. What measure do you have in mind?

Comment: I think, an outer measure is better (to begin) than a measure for your question, since you have in mind the power set of $ \mathbb{R}$. But, as @Ian said, what measure do you have in mind?

Comment: None specifically. I only need to know if my question make any sense with any probability measure, specially if the measure chosen is important to any probability theory. The fact is: I don't know any probability measure, I never studied them before, but I want to know if is possible to formulate my question rigorously and give it a answer or no.

Comment: You must define a measure for the Q to mean anything. There may be some measure that yield interesting ideas or results. You might also  find some that give easy answers,  but aren't interesting.

Comment: @FernandoVieiraCostaJúnior, I recommend you, from my personal point of view, two good books that can introduce you to Probability theory. The first one is Theory of Probability and Random Processes (Koralov-Sinai), the second one is Measure Theory (Cohn). The last one is more difficult. Both books are available on Internet. I recommend you to read the first two chapters from each book.                                          I think your question is too wide to be responded here. For example, we can't always define a measure on the power set of a set.

Comment: @DonQuixote Thanks! I will take a look. =D